# Background Picture

Tags: beamer, packages, diagrams

I am creating a presentation using the Beamer document class. I was wondering if it would be possible to have the same picture appear as a background of each slide.

This is the image I am referring to.
[image]

I want to be able to put the outline on the side strip if possible. Is there any particular theme that allows me to do so? Any usepackages I will need?

Thanks in advanced for all the help.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one possibility using the `sidebar` outer theme;  the `background canvas` template was used to include the image in the background; the `headline` and `frametitle` templates were also redefined to take into account the width of the left image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
  {%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
    \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
      \vfil
      \leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin%
      \advance\leftskip by1cm%
      \rightskip=-\beamer@rightmargin%
      \advance\rightskip by0.3cm plus1fil%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par}%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\par}%
      \vbox{}%
      \vskip-1em%
      \vfil
    }%
  }
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
 \makeatother
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1cm,text margin right=0.5cm}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{kodvZ}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test tile}
\framesubtitle{Test subtile}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of example code]